# many to many domains relationship while saving

Tags: grails

i have 2 domains the relationship between them is one to many, Advertisement :

```
class Advertisement {

String adDetails
String adTitle
Category category


static belongsTo = [user:Users]
static hasMany=[adsPhotos:Photos] 
}
```

Domain Photos:

```
class Photos {
Date dateCreated
byte [] photo
Date lastUpdated



static belongsTo =[users:Users,ads:Advertisement,profiles:Profile]
 }
```

while creating an advertisement you may need to upload a picture , so there is a link in the Ads create page to let go to the Photos create page as shown in the image:

[image]

how i could pause the photo domain saving while the users go back to the Ads creation page and fill the fields and save it , as the photo object needs Ads ID so i can't save the photo till the Ad is saved .
So how i could do that , or may someone got a better idea rather what i reached

Answer (score 0):

According to your example code, you actually have a one-to-many from `Advertisement` to `Photo`. A many-to-many requires a `hasMany` on both sides of the association. With a many-to-many you can create a `Photo`  independently from an `Advertisement`. You can see an example of a many-to-many [here](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/).

As for the views, navigating to another view and then back while retaining context (the unsaved `Advertisement`) would be tricky. You may be able to craft something using the **flash scope**, but see if the [Spring Web Flow plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/webflow) fits what you'd like to do.

Comment: ya , is there any other way rather the using the plugin?

Comment: If the plugin can do it, you can certainly do it by hand. But it's likely to be a real pain in the you know what. The issue is keeping the unsaved (detached) advertisement around through multiple requests. Off hand, I don't know how to do that.